# Athena not collecting results for a portion of files in Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I've tried to find similar issues on here/online, but came up short.

I have Athena pointing to a folder in Amazon S3 which itself contains folders/partitions each with a single .tsv inside (e.g. `s3://my_bucket/partition/file.tsv`). Athena is able to collect results for the majority of the files in the bucket, but doesn't collect results for a small number of them.

I've run the repair code (`MSCK REPAIR TABLE`) and I checked glue to make sure that it is seeing the partitions (it is). I also checked the Amazon knowledge center (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/athena-empty-results/). Not sure what else might be causing the issue.

Comment: Very hard to say. It happens to me once when I was moving data from Impala to Athena. The buckets were created in S3 but not properly. I started from scrach and it worked. I am saying that because I also had to run `MSCK REPAIR TABLE`. I was killing the migration process after 2 minutes (because it was a test) and this results in inconsistent buckets. Maybe if you describe in detail your steps then it is better to reason about it.

Comment: Can you move the 'bad' files to a different location to see if it works? How many partitions are there?

Comment: Please provide the table DDL (CREATE TABLE …) and example listings from S3.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the columns of the tables (pulled from an API) were in a different order for the files that were not working. Running the queries on a different field provided results. The solution was to enforce the order of the columns were consistent after collecting data from the API.